# SQL - adding a percentage to a column

Tags: sql, percentage

I am attempting to show "what if" information from one column into a new one. The scenario is taking a number, and adding 10% to it to show in the new column. I am at a complete loss of how to even begin this one!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (e.g., MySQL, Oracle, MongoDB, Microsoft SQL Server...)

Comment: The answer by @rufanov is so trivial that it's hard to believe that it was really what you had trouble with. Could you clarify your question by adding a data sample and the expected result for it?

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
SELECT old_value, old_value + (old_value * 0.1) as new_value FROM sometable
```

0.1 there is 10 percent(1/10).

or just:

```
SELECT old_value, old_value * 1.1 as new_value FROM sometable
```

so there you calculate 110% from old value.

Answer (score 0):

You can update employee by setting `sal=sal+sal*0.1;`

Comment: This is not what OP needs... He want to show a new column rather than updating an existing column.